# show results of several APIs in php js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, api

I am a little novice in php, js and I need to make a script that scans an API URL https://api.example.com/userid

Where **userid** has to be scanned from 0 to 100 and only shows API results that contain values ​​in a specific array and those that do not have content in that array, which simply does not show them.

I would appreciate it with all my heart, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `for` loop. In your api.php file, you do not need to specify a query parameter if you only want to scan 100 rooms. If I've understood correctly, what you retrieve from the API is already JSON and that's why you're just outputting back whatever you get from that request.

You can do something like this:

```php
$data = ['rooms' => []];

for ($i = 1; $i < 101; $i++) {
  $url = 'https://www.api.example.com/'. $i. '-roomid';
  $result = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($result);

  if (!empty($json['members'])) {
    $data['rooms'][] = $json; // only append to the list if there are members
  }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

So, in my example above, I [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) a JSON string which creates a stdClass object. From there, you can parse whatever you get back from that API and build some sort of multidimensional array and [encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it. After you've encoded it, you can just echo it.

I can unfortunately not tell you anymore because I haven't seen the response from the API you're using.

Comment: I like it, I only have one question: how do I make the apis that have the empty array members not show?

Comment: Since you decode the JSON response from the API, you could try to do something like: `if (empty($json['members'])) continue;`, `continue` will skip to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: How can I add it to the code? Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: thank you so much, One last question, and if I want to show all the data in the html result? since in my function.js only one is shown

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question really. What exactly do you mean by show all data in the html result? Aren't you already doing that?